# how to show only multiple of 25 in a sql record?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a plenty of record in MedicineStock field. i would like to only show the multiple of 25 in MedicineStock..  multiple of 25 [ 50 - 75 - 100.. etc ]

here's query i try

```
SELECT MedicineID,MedicineName,MedicineStock
FROM c a, MsMedicineType b
WHERE a.MedicineTypeID = b.MedicineTypeID
AND MedicineStock = MedicineStock+25
ORDER BY MedicineName
```

but it's not working. i'm still student i try to read the modules the teacher give.. but don't find any good refreence for it. and already looking for some refreence in google and couldn't find it. i'm totally stuck. i hope i'll get to know how to do it. in here. thank you in advance

Comment: Could you use the MOD function in some way? Something like AND MOD(MedicineStock, 25) = 0? That probably is not the syntax, but may get you there somewhat.

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_mod.asp

Comment: Read up MOD function here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Comment: OMG. thanks a lot for these documentation link. i was searching it with my language keyboard.. cause i dont really know the english keyword for it. i'll read them carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MOD function which represents the modulus operation in math.
MOD() returns the remainder of a number divided by another number, in your case, all multiples of 25 have 0 as remainder.

```
SELECT MedicineID,MedicineName,MedicineStock
FROM c a, MsMedicineType b
WHERE a.MedicineTypeID = b.MedicineTypeID
AND MOD(a.MedicineTypeID,25) = 0
ORDER BY MedicineName
```

Comment: This answered the question. i learn something new today. thanks a lot